# match aggregation for array not working as expected Mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to find all record which exists between input arguments.
If I pass as both from and to arguments as same then It should find an exact match.

I have below query:

```
db.runCommand(
{
    aggregate: "mycoll",
    pipeline: [
        {
            "$match": {"NUM": {$gte: 25, $lte:25 } }
        }
    ]
}
)
```

**Collection Data:**

```
{"_id" : "1","NUM" : [21,24] }
{"_id" : "2","NUM" : [25,29] }
{"_id" : "3","NUM" : [24,26,28] }
```

**Output of above query:**

```
{"_id" : "2","NUM" : [25,29] }
{"_id" : "3","NUM" : [24,26,28] }   //Why this record come No any 25 record exits
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that your conditions are applied to the array separately. There is an item greater than `25` and there's also and item lower than `25` and that's why you get whole array. To fix that you need [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator:

```
{
    "$match": {
       NUM: {
          $elemMatch: {
              $gte: 25,
              $lte: 25
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @KamleshKanazariya please take a look here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/VXqMX6MxKS9